# Possibility of multiple shortest cycles in a directed and undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Is there any possibility that a weighted directed or undirected graph has more than one shortest cycle? I mean, the shortest cycles have the same total weights.

For example, in a shortest-directed cycle, let's say in both directions, the cycle has the same total weight. So, in this case, we have two shortest cycles. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a graph can have several shortest cycles. All you need to do is draw an example:

```
O --- 1
| \   |
|  \  |
|   \ |
2 --- 3
```

We can see that its shortest cycle has length *3*. One such cycle is *(0, 1, 3, 0)* and another is *(0, 3, 2, 0)*.

For directed simple graphs, you can find a similar trivial example.
For weigthed graphs, remember that every unweighted graph is a weighted graph (with weigth *1* everywhere).